# Dimension of a manifold when three functions are kinda linearly dependent

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

In my analysis textbook, I found the following problem:

$f,g,h:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ are $C^1$ such that
$$\forall x\in \Bbb{R}^n \exists a,b\in\Bbb{R}\space a\nabla g(x)+b\nabla h(x)=\nabla f(x)$$

The task is to prove that $M = \{x\in \Bbb{R}|f(x)=g(x)=h(x)\}$ is either empty or a $C^1$ manifold of dimension $n-3$.

Now I find it very odd that the dimension would be $n-3$, by my intuition it should be $n-2$.

I think it might be a mistake in the textbook but I wasn't able to prove this either way so I can't be sure.

Edit:
I defined $F(x)=(f(x)^2 + g(x)^2, h(x))$
Then of course $M$ is the set of vanishing points for $F$, that is $M =F^{-1}(0)$

I've shown that unless
$DF(x)=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \frac{dh(x)}{dx_1} & \cdots & \frac{dh(x)}{dx_n} \end{pmatrix}$

for all $x\in M$ then $M$ is in fact a manifold of dimension $n-2$.

Is that also the case when
$DF(x)=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \frac{dh(x)}{dx_1} & \cdots & \frac{dh(x)}{dx_n} \end{pmatrix}$?

Or is it possible for the dimension to be $n-3$ or even for $M$ to not be a manifold?

Comment: Your intuition seems right to me ... the hypothesis allows the possibility that $h(x)=f(x)$, for example.

Comment: The task doesn't make sense to me. Taking Greg Martin's idea one step further, the condition is trivially satisfied when $f = g = h$, but then $M = \Bbb R^n$, which is a manifold of dimension $n$.